# Button that overrides link

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I'm making a website where the starting page should act as a "gateway" to the rest of the site (it greets the user and a click anywhere links to the main website). This is the code for this:

```js
<template>
    <div onclick="window.location.href='#/ordering';" style="cursor:pointer; width:100%; height:100%;">
        <div id="textpage"> <h2>XXX </h2>
            <h3> {{ uiLabels.welcomeText }} </h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

The website is constructed so it can be displayed in two languages, where `uiLabels.thing` fetches "thing" in either language. I now want a button that changes the language. I've done this:

```js
<button v-on:click="switchLang()">{{ uiLabels.language }}</button>
```

where `switchLang()` is a method that switches the language variable, and thus will switch the displayed langue on my page. The only problem is that the link "overrides" the button, so when the button is pressed the user is linked to the main part of the website.

I want the button on the bottom left of the page.

- If I place the button code in a div before the link div it gets
  placed on top of the page, and it looks horrible.
- If I place the button in the link div it gets placed right under the
  welcome text, but can't be clicked.
- If I place it in a div after the link div I get a fail message saying
  that I can only have one root element.

One way around this is to place the button outside of the div that links, but if I do that that button can't be moved to where I want it.

Comment: can you show where you want the button, show us with the code where the button is currently

Comment: I want the button on the bottom left of the page. If I place the button code in a div before the link div it gets placed on top of the page, and it looks horrible. If I place the button in the link div it gets placed right under the welcome text, but can't be clicked. If I place it in a div after the link div I get a fail message saying that I can only have one root element.

Comment: is it a page with no scrolling? should the button be at the very bottom of the page or sticky (if it scrolls)? Can you wrap the link div and the button in a parent div?

Comment: The page looks like this: https://gyazo.com/449e9512fc36c39eace8d9efaa8311f6

Comment: If i put the button in a div before the link div it looks like this:https://gyazo.com/2385e3bdd036a2c999f4194793ea180a

Comment: "but if I do that that button can't be moved to where I want it." Sure it can. With CSS you can do practically anything ([paintings done only with HTML and CSS](https://twistedsifter.com/2019/11/painting-with-css-and-html-by-diana-smith/)). You just need to know how. Research [`position: absolute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third option is one way to go.

Add a wrapping element around the two elements and make the language button position absolute. Something like this:

```js
<template>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div @click="window.location.href='#/ordering';" style="cursor:pointer; width:100%; height:100%;">
            <div id="textpage"> <h2>XXX </h2>
                <h3> {{ uiLabels.welcomeText }} </h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="langPicker" @click="switchLang()">{{ uiLabels.language }}</button>
    </div>
</template>
```

And with CSS something like:

```css
.wrapper {
   position: realtive;
}

.langPicker {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 20px;
   right: 20px
}
```

This is just to give you an idea, you have to adjust it to suit your needs.